# Azure Web Jobs - Saving app settings to persist across restarts

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logic, azure-webjobs

### I have an Azure "Always-On" continuous web job running

My application does the following:

1. **Checks to see what the "Last Updated Record" was** using Application Settings. (Properties.Settings.Default.Property)
2. If the property has a value, it will **continue from this point when the application is restarted or gets aborted, etc.**. (sounds simple right?)

   This is ***not happening***, any ideas how I should persist the settings from the app?

I want to attempt to avoid any other service calls, is there an Azure Webjob's function for saving and retrieving settings that can be persisted across each restart?

Any ideas?

(and if my code has any optimization notes of interest, please comment)

```
    if (lastUpdatedRecord > 0)
                {
                    if (Properties.Settings.Default.lastUpdatedRecord >= maximum)
                    {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.lastUpdatedRecord = 0;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("I see were not done yet with our last run, resuming where we left off [" + lastUpdatedRecord + "]");
                        start = lastUpdatedRecord;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    start = gatherStart;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.lastUpdatedRecord = 0;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }

                for (i = start; i <= maximum; i++)
```

Comment: Doing some last minute searching I came across this nifty URL that I will attempt and report success or failure:   http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/16/configuring-azure-web-jobs/

Comment: no-go, this url class reference has a getter not a setter... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your are a looking for an [External Configuration Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589803.aspx)

The article explains how to implement the External Configuration Store pattern and you can find the source code [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41673).